# Open fileZilla on Client PC

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please anyone tell me how to Open fileZilla of client PC in ASP.net website.
We are providing functionality to allow admin to click on FTP link and download file ( HTMLs) and modify and Upload to server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot control the client's computer via server-side scripts. If you can it'd be a terrible world.

Comment: Even using JavaScript can't do that. Stop trying and tell the user to manually do that.

Comment: Thanks Alvin for the Reply.
My client right now doing same.
if we can do this then this is more optimal.

Comment: Alvin is wrong. Actually, you can control the client's computer via server-side scripts, quite easily, with ASP.net using Active X, but it requires special permissions in the browser and IE only...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give your users instructions on associating the filezilla application with ftp: links. See [this question over at SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/186563/associate-ftp-hyperlink-to-filezilla)

Comment: This is probably the best way to handle this problem. The PC will use whatever client is configured to do this. The advantage to a pure ftp link is that they may use a different, but equally full-featured, client.